# Unable to create a temporary file on Windows in C++ using tmpfnam

Tags: c++, file, temporary-files

I am trying to create a temporary file in my C++ program by calling the `tmpfnam` function to get the temporary file name and using that to create the file for writing, but my code is unable to create the temporary file. However, file creation works absolutely fine when I use a user-supplied file name or a string constant instead of using a temporary name from `tmpfnam`. Here is an example :

```
std::tmpnam(fname); //does not work 
std::fstream f(fname,std::ios::out);

char* fname = "myfile.txt"; //works
std::fstream f(fname,std::ios::out);
```

I checked that the file in case 2 is being created in the same directory as the source file, but not in case 1. I tried running the program under admin permissions as well and still no luck . Any idea why this is so ?

Comment: What are you passing to `tmpnam` ? Is it large enough ?

Comment: I find it surprising that you're able to write to the same directory as the executable. The executable must not be in a protected location.

Comment: @cnicutar `fname` is declared to be of size `L_tmpnam` so it should work fine.

Comment: @MarkRansom apologies for the typo , I have corrected that. I mean the directory with the source file.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried it [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/tmpnam) way?

```
char fname[L_tmpnam];
if (std::tmpnam(fname)) {
    std::fstream f(fname,std::ios::out);
    // ...
}
```

Hope that it helps.

Comment: I tried it this way, and std::tmpnam does return NULL. But then how do I create a temp file ?

Comment: @adi You can try the old C standby `tempnam` (see: [Open Group](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/tempnam.html) or [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs3e7355(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: Thank you Jeffrey, but I discovered that `tmpfnam` would return a temp file name with '\' prepended and since windows does not allow '\' in file names, my fstream object was failing to create a file.